# SQOOP: ERROR While import data from oracle db

Tags: sqoop

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found

.
.
.

Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
.
.
.
.
.
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

Comment: please give guidelines to import data using sqoop. I have given the proper user and pwd. while impot i got the error which is mentioned above.                                                                                                     INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
15/06/04 14:53:27 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1433331979484_0013 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1433331979484_0013_m_000000
Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0

Comment: Please mention what you tried so that tis error occurs. This will help you to get to your answer more quickly.

Comment: sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:xxxxx" --password "" --username "uname" --table "tabname" --target-dir "/h.../New_Dt" --verbose    is my command to import table from my db . But got errors which i mentioned above..

Comment: Please give me solution. It reads data from db.  And shows ....................... java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1ORA-01882: timezone region not found                                                                            ......                INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%                      ......                ERROR tool.ImportTool: Error during import: Import job failed!

Comment: I'm having this same issue.  Tried a bunch of things like setting oracle.sessionTimeZone and/or user.timezone to a specific timezone but still doesn't resolve the issue!  After many lines of the timezone issue, I get java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue Caused by: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.